# 2 divs on the left and the right of the wrapper, and to the infinity

Tags: html, wrapper, infinite

I have a wrapper which is 1024px width. And I need two divs;

One will be on the left side of the wrapper and another will be on the right side, but the significant point is that I want that divs infinite to the left and right.

Answer (score 0):

Start with 50% width for each and subtract half of your container width from that. And position them

```
.left, .right{
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(50% - 512px);
}

.left{
  left: 0;
}

.right{
  right: 0;
}
```

If this is for styling purposes it's a good idea to use pseudo elements. 
[Here's a fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/1swjzLbn/)